# The tooltip issue in ggplotly for error bars and bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, tooltip, plotly

I using ggplotly to plot a graph. I am using the tooltip function to represent the values in the barchart when the cursor is moved on the top of the graphs.

```
Source_Data <-
data.frame(
key = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
Product_Name = c(
  "Table",
  "Table",
  "Chair",
  "Table",
  "Bed",
  "Bed",
  "Sofa",
  "Chair",
  "Sofa"
 ),
 Product_desc = c("XX", "XXXX", "YY", "X", "Z", "ZZZ", "A", "Y", "A"),
 sd = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7, 0.8, 0.5),
 Cost = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

 )


ggplotly((
Source_Data %>%
ggplot(
  aes(
    Product_Name,
    Cost,
    ymin = Cost - sd,
    ymax = Cost + sd,
    fill = Product_desc,
    text = paste("Product Name:", Product_Name, "<br>", "Cost:", Cost)
  )
  ) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2(width = .9, preserve = "single")) +
  geom_errorbar(position = position_dodge2(
  width = .9,
  preserve = "single",
  padding = .5
  )) +
  geom_text(
  aes(y = Cost + sd, label = Cost),
  position = position_dodge2(width = .9),
  vjust = -1
  ) +
  facet_wrap( ~ key, scales = "free_x", strip.position = "bottom") +
  theme(strip.placement = "outside") +
  theme_bw()
  ),
  tooltip = "text"
  )
```

When i move the cursor over the bars I am getting the text values, thats fine. But when i move it on top of the error bars also I am getting the text values in different color. Is there a way that I can get the text/label values only on top the bars and not on the error bars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the `text` aesthetic in `geom_col`:

```
  Source_Data %>%
    ggplot(
      aes(
        Product_Name,
        Cost,
        ymin = Cost - sd,
        ymax = Cost + sd,
        fill = Product_desc
      )
    ) +
    geom_col(aes(text = paste("Product Name:", Product_Name, "<br>", "Cost:", Cost)),
             position = position_dodge2(width = .9, preserve = "single")) +
    ......
```

Comment: Hi Thank you so much :) Actually suggestion is making it to work. But my error bars are getting displaced because if this. Is there any reason for this ? When i add the aes in goem_col. This issue is taking place.